# Wordpress quick edit + add media buttons not working

Tags: javascript, wordpress

i just upgraded to Wordpres 3.6.1 and i have an issue, for the default twenty-twelve theme the add media and quick edit buttons work okay but when i created my own custom theme those buttons stopped working. I have not yet installed any plugins into my site and i have been searching for a solution for a while now, i need some help on this.

Some research i did suggested that it may be as a result of additional javascript files i added to my website, so i'm now wondering if there is special way to link these .js files in wordpress.

These are the scripts i'm currently using in the "header.php" file:

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/slider/anythingfader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/js/jquery.simplyscroll.min.js"></script>
```

Please note: This is NOT a graphical issue, like what was implied in a different but wordpress related post i made before.

Comment: did you remove (unenqueue) the jquery that is shipped with WordPress? There will be problems if you load a jquery additionally to the modified jquery that comes with wordpress.

Comment: You should enqueue the built-in WP jQuery, and *not* load your own as you have above.  Check out [wp_enqueue_script('jquery')](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

Comment: No i have not removed anything yet, i'm still a newbie to wordpress and this is my first custom wordpress site.

Comment: Okay but do i put the code within my functions.php file or within my header.php file?

Answer (score 0):

You should enqueue your scripts with wordpress if your adding additional scripts.

I would define the javascript directory in your functions.php file. Something like this:

Then create a function

```
define('MY_JS', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/js/' );


function reg_scripts() {
wp_register_script('jquery.easing.min', MY_JS .'jquery.easing.min.js', false, false, true);
wp_enqueue_script('jquery.easing.min');

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'reg_scripts' );
```

This should load it in the footer. Also - if your loading a different jquery then the one shipped it may prevent the other version from working. If you need to deregister the shipped jquery version
you can add this into the function above

```
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
```

Comment: Okay i tried it, didn't work, duno what i'm doing wrong.  However i did neglect to mention that most of the jquery is used in  my home.php file where i have my slider etc. does enqueueing the scripts also afect the home.php file?

Comment: Whoa. Ok so the backend quick edits and the add media do not work. Where are developing your theme? You can write an if statement to make your query only work on a particular page if you wanted.

if (is_page('our-people')) {

Comment: We dont know what your setup is. So its kind of hard to determine what is going on. Have you tried using _underscore theme. Its a blank theme to get you started building your own.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. I guess it has to do with the new version of Wordpress which is 3.6.1

```
<?php  echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri()?>/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
<?php  echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri()?>/slider/anythingfader.js">
<?php  echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri()?>/js/jquery.simplyscroll.min.js">
```